# Someone have a look at my source code for a number guessing game that seems to keep failing

Tags: java, object, if-statement, joptionpane

May someone run my code and assist me in debugging i I'm having a lot of troubles trying to figure it out and I have not a lot of guidance when it comes to coding.

The problem with my code right now is that it runs certain parts twice. Please annotate the issue and any
recommendations to fix it.

A brief of what I'm trying to do:
number guessing game. The idea is that the computer will generate a random number and will ask the user if they know the number. If the user gets the answer correct they will get a congrats message and then the game will end but if the user enters a wrong number they get a try again message and then they will try again

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.lang.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   /*
   number guessing game
    */

    enterScreen();
    if (enterScreen() == 0){
        number();
        userIn();
        answer();
    }


}
public static int enterScreen (){
   String[] options = {"Ofcourse", "Not today"};
    int front = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            "I'm thinking of a number between 0 and 100, can you guess what is is?",
            "Welcome",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options, "Yes" );
    if(front == 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodluck then, you might need it. :D");
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "okay i dont mind");
    }

    return front;
}
private static int number(){

    double numD;
    numD = (Math.random() * Math.random()) * 100;
    int numI = (int) numD;
    System.out.println(numD);

    return numI;
}
private static int userIn(){
    String userStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What number do you think im thinking of?");
    int user = Integer.parseInt(userStr);

    return 0;
}
private static void answer(){
    // here is the problem
    if(userIn() == number()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Well done! You must be a genius.");
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shame, TRY AGAIN!");
        userIn();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: which part is running twice? Or it's your suspicion?

Comment: [I downvoted because there appears to have been no effort to debug the code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: You’re calling the number and the userIn methods both separately and then again in the answer method. Learn to debug.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a "debug my code for me" site.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this part:

```
        enterScreen();
        if (enterScreen() == 0) {
            number();
            userIn();
            answer();
        }
```

You can leave out the first `enterScreen()`.   Because you call it again in the if statement. If you look at the return type of the method: `public static int`, it returns and int. This makes it so that the outcome of the method is directly available in the if statement. The fist `enterScreen` is basicly useless, because you dont use the result.
You could do this:

```
int num = enterscreen();
if (num == 0) {
            number();
            userIn();
            answer();
        }
```

Which is basicly the same as:

```
if (enterScreen() == 0) {
            number();
            userIn();
            answer();
        }
```

Comment: This answer only mentions one of several problems.

Comment: @Joakim True, but I am not going to chew his food for him. I'm not going to give a talk about division of UI and backend or something like MVC. I would like too, but that wasn't his question. Maybe I'll edit my answer tomorrow.

Comment: I was thinking more of the fact that enterScreen() is not the only method called twice...

Comment: @Joakim Fair enough, I missed that. I honestly stopped reading after the double enterScreen. Thought the double entry was coused by that same method as well.

Answer (score 0):

You call `enterScreen()` twice. Just call it once, and compare the value returned only once.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you think that it's a bad question, why did you answer rather than comment asking the OP to improve it?

Comment: Mostly because I just got the 'comment anywhere' privilege. And didn't think to use it for that. I've been using it to look up solutions for a while, but haven't created an account until recently. I know in part how StackOverflow works, but I am relatively new to actually posting.

Comment: Your rep is 64 - you can comment everywhere now.

Answer (score 0):

You call `enterScreen()` and `userIn()` functions twice or more. Please Computer Science and coding. **Hint**: Computer's execute intructions from top to bottom.